# Speed difference in using inline strings vs concatenation in php5?

Tags: php, optimization, performance

(assume php5) consider

```
<?php

    $foo = 'some words';

    //case 1
    print "these are $foo";

    //case 2
    print "these are {$foo}";

    //case 3
    print 'these are ' . $foo;
?>
```

Is there much of a difference between 1 and 2?

If not, what about between 1/2 and 3?

Comment: Note that `echo 'these are ', $foo;` is faster than any of those, since there is no concatenation or interpolation.

Comment: Why on Earth is this question not constructive?

Comment: No idea. It was really a seed question, added shortly after the start of the site, when the beta people were encouraged to post baseline questions that would come up in early google searches, even if they were far too simple of a question, or bordering on non-question form. Given the views and activity of comments and voting therein, I'd say it was pretty constructive, imho.

Comment: Please see my answer to another question, where this issue has come up in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31312867/2893496

Comment: Single quotes are faster in my scenario. I run asynchronous log parsers using parallel, the performance boost in CPU gave-me the oportunity to run more parsers in parallel. Single quoted I can parse 144TB/hour double quoted I can parse less than 95TB. But you will only need to check it when you already did all of the things you could === instead of ==, string comparsion instead of regex and tons of others.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, as with all "What might be faster in real life" questions, you can't beat a real life test.

```
function timeFunc($function, $runs)
{
  $times = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $runs; $i++)
  {
    $time = microtime();
    call_user_func($function);
    $times[$i] = microtime() - $time;
  }

  return array_sum($times) / $runs;
}

function Method1()
{ 
  $foo = 'some words';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
    $t = "these are $foo";
}

function Method2()
{
  $foo = 'some words';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
    $t = "these are {$foo}";
}

function Method3()
 {
  $foo = 'some words';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
    $t = "these are " . $foo;
}

print timeFunc('Method1', 10) . "\n";
print timeFunc('Method2', 10) . "\n";
print timeFunc('Method3', 10) . "\n";
```

Give it a few runs to page everything in, then...

0.0035568

0.0035388

0.0025394

So, as expected, the interpolation are virtually identical (noise level differences, probably due to the extra characters the interpolation engine needs to handle). Straight up concatenation is about 66% of the speed, which is no great shock. The interpolation parser will look, find nothing to do, then finish with a simple internal string concat. Even if the concat were expensive, the interpolator will still have to do it, **after** all the work to parse out the variable and trim/copy up the original string.

**Updates By Somnath:**

I added Method4() to above real time logic.

```
function Method4()
 {
  $foo = 'some words';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
    $t = 'these are ' . $foo;
}

print timeFunc('Method4', 10) . "\n";

Results were:

0.0014739
0.0015574
0.0011955
0.001169
```

When you are just declaring a string only and no need to parse that string too, then why to confuse PHP debugger to parse. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Surely you can't beat a real life test. But this artificial frankenstein has nothing in common with the real life conditions.

Comment: Those skeptics trying to reproduce these results (like me ;-) on PHP5+ change the `microtime()` calls to `microtime(true)` - you want the time as a float, not as some sort of weird string.

Comment: Added Method4() for string processing. And I think PHP processing got more faster now. @AdamWright

Comment: Hello. Your comparison assumes that there is but a single instance of the variable within a string. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31312867/2893496

Comment: This confuses me: "about 66% of the speed", ain't that "about 66% of the time"? I thought concatenation is faster?

Answer (score 108):

The performance difference has been [irrelevant](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html) since at least January 2012, and likely earlier:

```
Single quotes: 0.061846971511841 seconds
Double quotes: 0.061599016189575 seconds
```

Earlier versions of PHP may have had a difference - I personally prefer single quotes to double quotes, so it was a convenient difference. The conclusion of the article makes an excellent point:

> Never trust a statistic you didn’t forge yourself.

(Although the article quotes the phrase, the original quip was likely falsely [attributed](http://www.statistik.baden-wuerttemberg.de/Service/Veroeff/Monatshefte/20041111.mha) to Winston Churchill, invented by Joseph Goebbels' propaganda ministry to portray Churchill as a liar:

> Ich traue keiner Statistik, die ich nicht selbst gefälscht habe.

This loosely translates to, "I do not trust a statistic that I did not fake myself.")

Comment: Although the performance difference is a few milliseconds... but I suppose it can add up

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a compile-time check?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't know this and was about to make fun of the question... is there any way to get your single quoted string to be parsed again?

Comment: And, on top of that, by using less pixels, you reduce greenhouse emissions.

Comment: "Wouldn't this just be a compile-time check?"-nobody
Why yes it would.  It's a scripted language, so compile time is run time.

Comment: Actually, since faster computation means less CPU time means less watts consumed, single quotes really do reduce greenhouse emissions.

Comment: @Paolo Begantino: do you actually have any proof of this?  http://www.phpbench.com/ respectfully disagrees with you every time I load it.

Comment: @A.Rex: Mm. To be honest, I don't. I don't know if it has been handled in latest versions or what, my answer was just what I've picked up through time and what I reasoned. I'll look into it some more I guess.

Comment: I've also found double quotes to be slightly faster. (Though my argument is always about readability, which double quotes win.)

Comment: Your example is flawed, as it does no concatenation with single quotes.

Comment: Note that even if you use a single-quoted string, PHP is still parsing over every character in it, to look for escape sequences, etc. PHP is also parsing the entire _file_, so at best, you're still looking at O(n) for the length of the string.

Comment: @A. Rex: I think it all depends on the size of the string and the number of variable present in it. Double quote needs some time to parse variables; some variables could be a complex object which has a method toString()

Comment: This is incorrect in any modern install of PHP, and should be adjusted. There is no measurable difference: http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

Comment: Yes, in earlier versions of PHP (<= 4.3) there was a trivial but measurable difference (on the order of microseconds). Since 4.4 the parser works differently which basically sped up double quotes to be the same for the vast majority of cases. Either way, the difference is so minute that it's a micro-optimization to even consider the difference...

Comment: You need to use ' with php as html has " marks everywhere.

Answer (score 25):

Live benchmarks:

http://phpbench.com/

There is actually a subtle difference when concatenating variables with single vs double quotes.

Comment: I think that it depends on hardware configuration and compiled php.

Comment: I didn't know you could use a comma in echo, instead of dot.

Answer (score 18):

@Adam's test used

```
"these are " . $foo
```

note that the following is even faster:

```
'these are ' . $foo;
```

this is due to the fact, that a double quoted "string" gets evaluated, where a single quoted 'string' is just taken as is...

Comment: I've just done some quick testing and there's not much of a saving between these two - certainly nowhere near as much as changing interpolation to concatenation - but single quotes are faster.

Answer (score 13):

Don't get too caught up on trying to optimize string operations in PHP. Concatenation vs. interpolation is meaningless (in real world performance) if your database queries are poorly written or you aren't using any kind of caching scheme. Write your string operations in such a way that debugging your code later will be easy, the performance differences are negligible.

@uberfuzzy Assuming this is just a question about language minutia, I suppose it's fine. I'm just trying to add to the conversation that comparing performance between single-quote, double-quote and heredoc in real world applications in meaningless when compared to the real performance sinks, such as poor database queries.

Answer (score 10):

Any differences in execution time are completely negligible.

Please see

- [NikiC's Blog: Disproving the Single Quotes Performance Myth](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html) for a technical explanation how interpolation and concatenation works in PHP and why it is absolutely pointless to care about their speed.

Don't waste time on micro-optimizations like this. Use a profiler to measure the performance of your application in a real world scenario and then optimize where it is really needed. Optimising a single sloppy DB query is likely to make a bigger performance improvement than applying micro-optimisations all over your code.

Comment: Amen!  I've noticed that in different language communities different things are valued, and the performance of single quotes seems to be a sacred cow of the PHP world.

Answer (score 4):

there is a difference when concatenating variables... and what you are doing with the result... and if what you are doing is dumping it to output, is or isn't output buffering on.

also, what is the memory situation of the server?  typically memory management on a higher level platform is worse than that at lower platforms...

```
$a = 'parse' . $this;
```

is managing memory at the user code platform level...

```
$a = "parse $this";
```

is managing memory at the php system code platform level...

so these benchmarks as related to CPU don't tell the full story.

running the benchmark 1000 times vs running the benchmark 1000 times on a server that is attempting to run that same simulation 1000 times concurrently... you might get drastically different results depending on the scope of the application.

Comment: Plus 1 for " typically memory management on a higher level platform is worse than that at lower platforms... "

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember that the developer of the forum software, Vanilla replaced all the double quotes in his code with single quotes and noticed a reasonable amount of performance increase.

I can't seem to track down a link to the discussion at the moment though.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something else to the mix, if you are using a variable inside a double quoted string syntax:

```
$foo = "hello {$bar}";
```

is faster than

```
$foo = "hello $bar";
```

and both of these are faster than

```
$foo = 'hello' . $bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes can be much slower. I read from several places that that it is better to do this

```
'parse me '.$i.' times'
```

than

```
"parse me $i times"
```

Although I'd say the second one gave you more readable code.

Comment: Uh, no: in my experience working with other people's code, the first one is much more readable.

Comment: @staticsan just get yourself good editor with syntax highlighting, dude.

Comment: I *do* use a syntax-highlighting editor. The highlighting works much better with the first variant.

Comment: PhpStorm editor works good with highlighting on both examples.

Comment: `I read from several places` - What places? Please provide documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Practically there is no difference at all! See the timings: http://micro-optimization.com/single-vs-double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that, when using a modified version of the example by Adam Wright with 3 variables, the results are reversed and the first two functions are actually faster, consistently. This is with PHP 7.1 on CLI:

```
function timeFunc($function, $runs)
{
    $times = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $runs; $i++)
    {
        $time = microtime();
        call_user_func($function);
        @$times[$i] = microtime() - $time;
    }

    return array_sum($times) / $runs;
}

function Method1()
{ 
    $foo = 'some words';
    $bar = 'other words';
    $bas = 3;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
         $t = "these are $foo, $bar and $bas";
}

function Method2()
{
    $foo = 'some words';
    $bar = 'other words';
    $bas = 3;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
         $t = "these are {$foo}, {$bar} and {$bas}";
}

function Method3()
{
    $foo = 'some words';
    $bar = 'other words';
    $bas = 3;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
         $t = "these are " . $foo . ", " . $bar . " and " .$bas;
}

print timeFunc('Method1', 10) . "\n";
print timeFunc('Method2', 10) . "\n";
print timeFunc('Method3', 10) . "\n";
```

I've also tried with '3' instead of just the integer 3, but I get the same kind of results.

With $bas = 3:

```
0.0016254
0.0015719
0.0019806
```

With $bas = '3':

```
0.0016495
0.0015608
0.0022755
```

It should be noted that these results vary highly (I get variations of about 300%), but the averages seem relatively steady and almost (9 out of 10 cases) always show a faster execution for the 2 first methods, with Method 2 always being slightly faster than method 1.

In conclusion: what is true for 1 single operation (be it interpolation or concatenation) is not always true for combined operations.

Comment: I wonder how much of this is from the flipping, and how much of it was optimizations in php7. The original question was specific to mention a context of `php5`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, originally this is about PHP5, however in few months arrive PHP8 and today the best option tested over my **PHP 7.4.5** is use [PHP - Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (tested over WIN 10 + Apache and CentOs 7 + Apache):

```
function Method6(){
    $k1 = 'AAA';
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i ++)$t = <<<'EOF'
K1= 
EOF
.$k1.
<<<'EOF'
K2=
EOF
.$k1;
    }
```

here the method #5 (using **Heredoc** to concatenat):

```
function Method5(){
    $k1 = 'AAA';
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i ++)$t = <<<EOF
K1= $k1
EOF
.<<<EOF
K2=$k1 
EOF;
    }
```

the methods 1 to 4 is in beginning of this post

In all my tests the "winner" is method #6 (Newdoc), no't very easy to read, but very fast in CPU and ever using the function `function timeFunc($function)` by **@Adam Wright**.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested php 7.4 and php 5.4 with following test cases, It was little still confusing to me.

```
<?php
$start_time = microtime(true);
$result = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 700000; $i++) {
    $result .= "THE STRING APPENDED IS " . $i;
    // AND $result .= 'THE STRING APPENDED IS ' . $i;
    // AND $result .= "THE STRING APPENDED IS $i";
}
echo $result;
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "<br><br>";
echo ($end_time - $start_time) . " Seconds";
```

PHP 7.4 Outputs

```
 1. "THE STRING APPENDED IS " . $i = 0.16744208335876
 2. 'THE STRING APPENDED IS ' . $i = 0.16724419593811
 3. "THE STRING APPENDED IS $i" = 0.16815495491028
```

PHP 5.3 Outputs

```
 1. "THE STRING APPENDED IS " . $i = 0.27664494514465
 2. 'THE STRING APPENDED IS ' . $i = 0.27818703651428
 3. "THE STRING APPENDED IS $i" = 0.28839707374573
```

I have tested so many times, In php 7.4 it seems to be all 3 test cases got same result many times but still concatenation have little bittle advantage in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @adam-wright answer, I wanted to know if speed difference happens without no concataining / no vars in a string.

**== My questions...**

- is `$array['key']` call or set faster than `$array["key"]` !?
- is `$var = "some text";` slower than `$var = 'some text';` ?

**== My tests** with new vars every time to avoid use same memory address :

```
function getArrDblQuote() { 
    $start1 = microtime(true);
    $array1 = array("key" => "value");
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
        $t1 = $array1["key"];
    echo microtime(true) - $start1;
}
function getArrSplQuote() {
    $start2 = microtime(true);
    $array2 = array('key' => 'value');
    for ($j = 0; $j < 10000000; $j++)
        $t2 = $array2['key'];
    echo microtime(true) - $start2;
}

function setArrDblQuote() { 
    $start3 = microtime(true);
    for ($k = 0; $k < 10000000; $k++)
        $array3 = array("key" => "value");
    echo microtime(true) - $start3;
}
function setArrSplQuote() {
    $start4 = microtime(true);
    for ($l = 0; $l < 10000000; $l++)
        $array4 = array('key' => 'value');
    echo microtime(true) - $start4;
}

function setStrDblQuote() { 
    $start5 = microtime(true);
    for ($m = 0; $m < 10000000; $m++)
        $var1 = "value";
    echo microtime(true) - $start5;
}
function setStrSplQuote() {
    $start6 = microtime(true);
    for ($n = 0; $n < 10000000; $n++)
        $var2 = 'value';
    echo microtime(true) - $start6;
}

print getArrDblQuote() . "\n<br>";
print getArrSplQuote() . "\n<br>";
print setArrDblQuote() . "\n<br>";
print setArrSplQuote() . "\n<br>";
print setStrDblQuote() . "\n<br>";
print setStrSplQuote() . "\n<br>";
```

**== My Results :**

array get **double** quote **2.1978828907013**

array get **single** quote **2.0163490772247**

array set **double** quote **1.9173440933228**

array get **single** quote **1.4982950687408**

var set **double** quote **1.485809803009**

var set **single** quote **1.3026781082153**

**== My conclusion !**

So, result is that difference is not very significant. However, on a big project, I think it can make the difference !