# php combining url with variable

Tags: php, variables

I want to do define the following variable $url

```
$url = www.example.com/$link;
```

where $link is another predefined variable text string e.g. testpage.php

But the above doesn't work, how do I correct the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Did we all posted at the same time? I swear when I saw this question there was no answer and now there are 5 lol

Comment: You can use this script PHP:

https://eval.in/608533

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "www.example.com/$link";
```

When string is in [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) you can put variables inside it. Variable value will be inserted into string.

You can also use [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to join 2 strings:

```
$url = "www.example.com/" . $link;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the first already and it failed but concatenation worked a treat.

$link is a double array so maybe that's why

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hate to duplicate an answer, but use single quotes to prevent the parser from having to look for variables in the double quotes.  A few ms faster..

```
$url = 'www.example.com/' . $link;
```

EDIT: And yes.. where performance really mattered in an ajax backend I had written, replacing all my interpolation with concatenation gave me a 10ms boost in response time.  Granted the script was 50k.

Comment: Is it *really* a few *milliseconds* faster? Frankly, this is precisely where variable interpolation is useful - sure, if you have a string with no variable interpolation in, use single quotes, but this seems like a ridiculous premature optimisation that slightly damages readability.

Comment: Call me anal, but I also replace all common URL's with constants.

Comment: @Rob: Not to be be a  moron, but... a few *milliseconds* is actually a huge deal in the programming world. If they stack up, you've got a slow script on your hands. Were you meaning *microseconds*? There's a big difference.

Comment: This is not plausible. The difference in execution speed will be micro or nano-seconds, if it is even measurable. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5

Answer (score 1):

Needs double quotes:

```
$url = "www.example.com/$link";
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way:

```
$url = "www.example.com/{$link}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "www.example.com/$link";
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful if you included the erroneous output, but as far as I can tell, you forgot to add double quotes:

```
$url = "www.example.com/$link";
```

You will almost certainly want to prepend "http://" to that url, as well.