# How do I add a php variable to this jquery url setting?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make the URL in the following example contain a php variable like this:

```
http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/$company.js
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
        }
```

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: you can refer this question also-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616231/php-combining-url-with-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to output the variable as JavaScript from PHP at some point in the script. This can be done quite easily using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var company = <?php echo json_encode($company) ?>;
```

Note that this will have to be placed in a file that is actually executed by PHP, rather than an inert .js file. One way to achieve this is to put it in an inline `<script>` in the HTML in your PHP template; e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var company = <?php echo json_encode($company) ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var company = <?php echo json_encode($company); ?>;
    alert(company);
</script>
```

You're setting the company variable with the output of `$company`, you can then use this variable however you please in JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/" + company + ".js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
}
```

Comment: Parentheses missing and a string containing `"` or `\` at the end will break things...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, assuming you have the company name in the php $company variable:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/<?php echo $company ?>.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
}
```