# How to show numerical date in mm/dd/yy format

Tags: php, format, date

Right now i am the month, day, and year of a user seperated in three db fields titled month, day, year.

When i display it i am doing:

```
$month = $row['month'];
$day = $row['day'];
$year = $row['year'];
```

then to echo it:

```
$month/$day/$year
```

The problem is that the PHP is doing mathematics here and dividing the numbers... What can i do to not make that happen and let it simply display the dates..

Thanks

Comment: After correcting your code to use string concatenation, fix your database to use a single `DATE` field.

Comment: Great tip konforce! Was thinking about that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out :

```
echo "{$month}/{$day}/{$year}";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date('m/d/Y',strtotime($month . ' ' . $day . ' ' . $year));
```

The advantage of this is that you can choose how to format the date independent of how it is stored in your database: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year;
```

Doing [string concatenation.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

or

```
echo "{$month}/{$day}/{$year}";
```

Doing string interpolation.

See the difference/performance of the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5).