# How to end a variable name in string without space

Tags: php

How can I end a variable name in a string without using space or any other special character?

Example is there anything I can put between `$num` and `st` to output `1st` instead of `1 st`

```
$num = 1;
echo "$num st";
```

Without using the dot opperator for concatination

Comment: Yes, you must never use concatenation... even if it gives you the output you need, it's just so evil and wrong

Comment: @MarkBaker Are you serious or being sarcastic??

Comment: Perhaps I needed to be more sarcastic, as it clearly wasn't obvious that I was being so

Comment: I thought so, but I wasn't sure, seeing as some people definitely have very strong opinions about things like this, strangely enough :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap the name of the variable with braces.

```
$num = 1;
echo "${num}st";
```

Or use `printf` syntax instead of simple interpolation:

```
$num = 1;
printf("%dst", $num);
```

Comment: I though you had to type `"{$num}st"`. I guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: @RobinCastlin, If you type `{$num}st`, You'' get `{1}st` as output, not `1st`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenating `.` character:

```
echo $num . 'st';
```

Comment: The reason I asked this question was becouse concatination is a rather costly opperator and the code become hard to read but thanks anyway

Comment: That's simply not true, concatenation is actually slightly faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5 (though you shouldn't make a decision based on that speed difference, its negligible)

Comment: Have you actually measured the cost difference between using concatenation and other options such as those posted by Quentin... unless you're talking about concatenating significant numbers of strings that are all several thousands of bytes in length, it's almost immeasurable

Comment: Well it's not costly in speed but in memory usage. A concatination stores every string and then concatinates them. This leads to that a concatination uses double the memory

Comment: @nist - that memory overhead is temporary, until it's completed the concatenation operation, which is why it's only significant for extremely long strings, and even then it's for the few nanosconds that it takes to execute the concatenation itself.

Comment: @nist - but if you're concatenating purely to echo, don't. Use comma (,) instead of dot (.) so echo $num , 'st'; and you'll find it's mocroscopically more efficient in both memory and speed (though the difference is microscopic)