# Interpolation (insert string directly) VS concatenation in the performance aspect

Tags: php, string, performance, string-concatenation

Which is below method is faster when combining 2 strings ? And why can it run faster?

PHP code:

```
$str1 = 'Hello';
$str2 = 'World';
```

method 1:

```
$txt = $str1.$str2;
```

method 2:

```
$txt = "$str1$str2";
```

Comment: Build a benchmark test and test it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed difference in using inline strings vs concatenation in php5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5)

Answer (score 5):

**Opcode comparison**

Code:

```
$a=1; 
$b=2; 
echo "$a$b";
```

Opcodes:

```
   1     0  >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 1
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !1, 2
         2      ADD_VAR                                          ~2      !0
         3      ADD_VAR                                          ~2      ~2, !1
         4      ECHO                                                     ~2
         5    > RETURN                                                   null
```

Code:

```
$a=1; 
$b=2; 
echo $a.$b;
```

Opcodes:

```
   1     0  >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 1
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !1, 2
         2      CONCAT                                           ~2      !0, !1
         3      ECHO                                                     ~2
         4    > RETURN                                                   null
```

**Intermediate conclusion**

Concatenation has one less opcode, rejoice! Not really, we still have to test the actual runtime performance.

To see the opcodes generated by any piece of code, have a look at the great [`vld` extension](http://pecl.php.net/vld)

**Runtime performance**

Ran over 0.5m iterations on a workstation (average over 10 runs):

- Inlined: 0.9793s
- Concatenated: 0.9252s

**Conclusion**

Concatenation is faster, though it's unlikely to impact the performance of any particular application.

Comment: How do you know one `CONCAT` is faster than two `ADD_VAR`s?

Comment: Where can I get such a print of the opcodes?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha [`vld`](http://pecl.php.net/vld)

Comment: @Gumbo substantiated with runtime performance test.

Comment: What version of php did you use  ?

Comment: I meant what version of `vld` just noticed that `EXT_STMT` was not captured in your output or you just filtered the essential parts

Comment: @Baba Oh, it's 0.11.2; what's `EXT_STMT` supposed to do?

Comment: @Jack: You can not compare opcodes and then think less is faster. Johannes Schlüter explained that in one presentation better than I could do, I suggest to take some looks around if you are concerned about internals.

Comment: @hakre Perhaps the first sentence under 'Intermediate conclusion' was not phrased properly, but the answer covers both opcode analysis and runtime performance.