# String concatenation in PHP (with a variable inside of it) , which one has a better performance?

Tags: php, performance, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have these two codes in PHP:

```
$msgs = 5;
//These two types of string concatenation

echo 'You got ' . $msgs . ' messages';

echo "You got $msgs messages";
```

Comment: There are places online where you can test this. For such a low iteration the performance differences would be negligible.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Which places then? Instead of -'ing me, help me.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5 :)

Comment: -'ing you? I'm not -'ing you. I *do* have to ask if you Googled for this info because it looks like you put no effort into finding the answer before coming here.

Comment: Here, have a read of a [comprehensive study of various string-related optimizations](http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make some new test, is really simple

[Live example](http://ideone.com/mBBzv7)

#### Test

```
<?
$str1 = $str2 = "";

for ($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $str1 .= 'You got ' . $i . ' messages';
    $str1_test[] = microtime(true) - $start;
}

echo "Dotted: " . ($str1_result = array_sum($str1_test) / 10000);

echo PHP_EOL;

for ($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $str2 .= "You got {$i} messages";
    $str2_test[] = microtime(true) - $start;
}

echo "Interpolated: " . ($str2_result = array_sum($str2_test) / 10000);
echo PHP_EOL . ($str2_result < $str1_result ? "Interpolation" : "Dot") . " is faster!";
```

#### Result

```
Dotted: 1.1234998703003E-6
Interpolated: 1.2600898742676E-6
Dot is faster!
```

---

#### Real fact

The difference is to small to be significative, I personally like the interpolation, is elegant and faster to read, is up to you! ;)

Comment: Good answer, although I would say the differences are so negligible here, they'd get lost in the background noise of normal machine operation; ie: the difference would be within the margin of error. To add to this: there's cases wherein either approach make for more elegant code. If one is embedding dynamic values in a literal "template" string, interpolation is - IMO - more clear. If one has a number of strings to concatenate: use the concatenation operator. Use the most appropriate approach for the job, rather than worrying about negligible performance considerations.

Comment: @AdamCameron you are totally right. Also the interpolation doesn't work for complex operators/expresions :(

Comment: Yeah, that sux a bit. Am just in the process of learning PHP (come from CFML), and have been bitten on the bum by that fairly frequently. CFML is more forgiving in that area than PHP. I'm erring towards using `printf()` / `sprintf()` in those situations, but still "it depends".