# Performance: " or ' PHP

Tags: php, performance, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm working on a big project in php and I need to make sure it's all fast. So I'm wondering: *what is faster to use, **"** or **'** ?* (Eg: `$_SESSION['example']` or `$_SESSION["example"]`)

Comment: everything within " " wil be analysed and everything within ' ' not

Comment: Write a benchmark and test it. In my experience, `"` is very slightly (~4%) faster. But note: this is probably a case of very premature optimization.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/13680/5515060

Comment: @Grumpy - not true, even strings inside `'` need to be analysed for escape characters

Comment: On a big project - It is most likely that database access will be a performance issue rather than parsing strings natively in PHP (which is a none issue anyway)?

Comment: You might save a moment when typing single quoted keys, as you won't have to hit the shift key. (Edit: true on US Qwerty layout, not on every layout i.e. Azerty.)

Comment: That sounds like an interesting project to work on. There is a lot to be learned from working on that project. Thanks for the update - I think you will have a lot of fun and interesting times - always try an enjoy it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't even care about this. It makes no real difference. No practical impact.

http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

https://speakerdeck.com/dshafik/phpaustralia-2015-php-under-the-hood

---

Lets use the same benchmark data from the post by Mark Smit:

> For a real speed benchmarks between quotes you can look at http://www.phpbench.com/

Q: **Is a there a difference in using double (") and single (') quotes for strings. Call 1'000x**

A: **In today's versions of PHP it looks like this argument has been satisfied on both sides of the line. Lets all join together in harmony in this one!**

Answer (score -5):

You should use ' because everything within " is analized, which makes it perform a lot slower. Right now magic quotes are even depricated. More information about that can be found on the [php](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php) website

For a real speed benchmarks between quotes you can look at [phpbench](http://www.phpbench.com/)

Comment: magic quotes has NOTHING to do with the choice of `'` or `"`...