# How do i write an email with php in it?

Tags: php, html

I am sending an email with PHP and i want the email sent to have PHP in it but for some reason it doesn't
work.
How can i include PHP in the email sent?
[This is the code that writes the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaQKX.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You don't want PHP in the mail. You want the content of variables (e.g. `$example`) in the string. That's part of any PHP tutorial out there -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't have php in an email, because emails can only have valid html/css code. What you want in your example is something like this:

```
$txt = '<th>' . $example . '</th>';
```

An alternative method of doing it would be as follows:

```
$txt = "<th> $example </th>";
```

In PHP, double quotation marks allow you to shove variables into the string and it automatically injects them in there. [Speed difference is negligible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620/speed-difference-in-using-inline-strings-vs-concatenation-in-php5), so you can use whichever fits your needs.